# Move a div below the current textarea (jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form with several textareas. As an editing aid the list div is filled via ajax with suggestions based on the current input and active textarea.

But the thing is I need to move this div below the active textarea.

I've got the current textarea id but can't find a way to move an element in this particular way.

```
<div id="list"></div>

            <dt><label for="mazas">Mazas:</label>

            <dd><textarea name="mazas" id="mazas" rows="1" cols="150"></textarea></dd>

            <dt><label for="rayos">Rayos:</label>

            <dd><textarea name="rayos" id="rayos" rows="1" cols="150"></textarea></dd>

            <dt><label for="llantas">Llantas:</label>

            <dd><textarea name="llantas" id="llantas" rows="1" cols="150"></textarea></dd>

            <dt><label for="cubiertas">Cubiertas:</label>

            <dd><textarea name="cubiertas" id="cubiertas" rows="1" cols="150"></textarea></dd>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To move it after the textarea with id `mazas`, for example:

```
$("#list").detach().insertAfter($("#mazas"));
```

Comment: mmm. It worked from the console ok, but I have the ID in a variable. How should I write that?

Comment: Is there any need of `.detach()` here?

Comment: @rahul no particular need, but i threw it in, since according to http://api.jquery.com/detach/, "this method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time."

Answer (score 0):

Set the div to have:

- position:absolute
- z-index:10 (*say*)
- top:0
- left:0

...then position using (e.g.):

```
$('#list').css('left', $('#mazas').offSet().left + 'px')
$('#list').css('top', $('#mazas').offSet().top + $('#mazas').height() + 5 + 'px')
```

...it'll then come be niceLy in position, and in front of everythiNg else so it won't break the rest of the page. use `fadeIn()` to make it really funky. (*You may need to use  parseInt on the strings, BTW*)

I use this *all* the time...